# Convert double into String 12Digit

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am converting double number into string but i am not getting as it is.
following is my code and result:

```
double d = 123456789123.0;
String test = String.valueOf(d);
System.out.println("InString"+test);
```

Result:

```
InString :1.23456789123E11
```

expected result: `123456789123.0`

Comment: try this. String test = d+"";

Comment: i have to convert into string not only printing, conversion does this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("000000000000.0");
    String test = nf.format(d);
```

Comment: Works fine but have to change `NumberFormat` into `DecimalFormat`

Answer (score 0):

Consider [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class from standard java library.

Use it's methods to format a double value.